How do I create a file in the non-protected area so I can access it from the Android file system?
I export some db info to a text file.
When I create the file the path is reported to be something like:
'/data/user/0/com.companyname.checkin/files/allscans-9-20-2024-11-55-50-am.txt'

How would I create this file in a "non-protected" accessible area of the file system?
Edit:
I tried the suggestion from Jason below (tx) but the file still seems to be created in a "protected" area even tho I tried to create it in the \DCIM dir.
string ExportFilenamePath;
#if ANDROID
    var docsDirectory = Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim);
    ExportFilenamePath = Path.Combine(docsDirectory.AbsoluteFile.Path, String.Format("allscans-{0}.txt", DtNow));
#else
    ExportFilenamePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, String.Format("allcans-{0}.txt", DtNow));
#endif          

Using this method the path is reported to be
All scans exported to/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.checkin/files/DCIM/allscans-9-20-2024-2-27-36-pm.txt.
What I really need to do is:
When I mount my phone with a USB cable to my PC I see these dirs in the root of the file system.
Phone\DCIM
Phone\Download
How do I create a file in This dir?
Phone\Download
I am testing on Android 8 but would like a solution that would run on any version 8+

Which version of Android are you using?
